# Range over an arbitrary type

Tags: iterator, go, range

Is there a way to make an arbitrary type `range`-able in Go? For example, Python offers `__iter__()`, which is really useful. I tried searching for the answer but I got no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've searched successfully, there's no support for ranging over arbitrary types in Go.

From the [specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

```
RangeClause = ( ExpressionList "=" | IdentifierList ":=" ) "range" Expression .
```

> The expression on the right in the "range" clause is called the range expression, which may be an array, pointer to an array, slice, string, map, or channel permitting receive operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use channels to simulate it. Something along the lines of

```
func (t *SomeType) Range() chan *Item {
    // setup a channel and a go routine that sends the items from t
}

for item := range t.Range() 
...
```